# Duplicate rows and change the sign of the first column of the duplicated rows in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am new to Python and Pandas.

I have a dataframe,`df_pos_alpha`,  of lift coefficient of a symmetrical airfoil for positive angles `alpha`. The dataframe has 59 rows and 11 columns and it looks like:

```
 alpha  Re1     Re2     Re3     Re4     Re5     Re6     Re7     Re8     Re9    Re10
   0  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
   1  0.0434  0.0891  0.1054  0.1100  0.1100  0.1100  0.1100  0.1100  0.1100  0.1100
   2  0.0715  0.1740  0.2099  0.2200  0.2200  0.2200  0.2200  0.2200  0.2200  0.2200
   3  0.0725  0.2452  0.3078  0.3300  0.3300  0.3300  0.3300  0.3300  0.3300  0.3300
   4  0.0581  0.3041  0.4186  0.4400  0.4400  0.4400  0.4400  0.4400  0.4400  0.4400

  ...  ....     ....    ....    ....    ....   ....     ....    ....    ....   ....  
  145 -0.9000 -0.9000 -0.9000 -0.9000 -0.9000 -0.9000 -0.9000 -0.9000 -0.9000 -0.9000
  150 -0.7700 -0.7700 -0.7700 -0.7700 -0.7700 -0.7700 -0.7700 -0.7700 -0.7700 -0.7700
  155 -0.6700 -0.6700 -0.6700 -0.6700 -0.6700 -0.6700 -0.6700 -0.6700 -0.6700 -0.6700
  160 -0.6350 -0.6350 -0.6350 -0.6350 -0.6350 -0.6350 -0.6350 -0.6350 -0.6350 -0.6350
  165 -0.6800 -0.6800 -0.6800 -0.6800 -0.6800 -0.6800 -0.6800 -0.6800 -0.6800 -0.6800
  170 -0.8500 -0.8500 -0.8500 -0.8500 -0.8500 -0.8500 -0.8500 -0.8500 -0.8500 -0.8500
  175 -0.6600 -0.6600 -0.6600 -0.6600 -0.6600 -0.6600 -0.6600 -0.6600 -0.6600 -0.6600
  180  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000
```

Because the airfoil is symmetric then its characteristics for negative angles is the same as for positive angles (The columns  `Re1` to `Re10` are the same for `alpha` and `-alpha`)

I want to get a new dataframe where `alpha` starts from -180 to 180.

I could achieve that as follows:

- Create another instance of the dataframe, `df_neg_alpha`, change the
  sign of the first column `alpha`, sort it by ascending `alpha`.
- append `df_pos_alpha` to `df_neg_alpha`.

**My question**: Is there any fast way or builtin method to achieve that?

Comment: `df_neg_alpha = df_pos_alpha.assign(alpha=lambda d: -d.alpha)`.  Then you can do a number of things but this should work. `df_neg_alpha.append(df_pos_apha).drop_duplicates('alpha').sort_values('alpha')`

Comment: Or `df_neg_alpha = df_pos_alpha.query('alpha != 0').assign(alpha=lambda d: -d.apha).sort_values('alpha')` Then do `df_neg_alpha.append(df_pos_alpha)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly we can copy `df_pos_alpha`, change the sign of `alpha` column then use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to append both dataframes over `axis=0` (eg: on top of each other) while using [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) ascending:

```
df_neg_alpha = df_pos_alpha.copy()
df_neg_alpha['alpha'] = -df_neg_alpha['alpha']
df_new = pd.concat([df_neg_alpha.sort_values('alpha'), 
                    df_pos_alpha], 
                    ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates('alpha')
```

---

```
print(df_new)
    alpha     Re1     Re2     Re3    Re4    Re5    Re6    Re7    Re8    Re9   Re10
0    -180  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
1    -175 -0.6600 -0.6600 -0.6600 -0.660 -0.660 -0.660 -0.660 -0.660 -0.660 -0.660
2    -170 -0.8500 -0.8500 -0.8500 -0.850 -0.850 -0.850 -0.850 -0.850 -0.850 -0.850
3    -165 -0.6800 -0.6800 -0.6800 -0.680 -0.680 -0.680 -0.680 -0.680 -0.680 -0.680
4    -160 -0.6350 -0.6350 -0.6350 -0.635 -0.635 -0.635 -0.635 -0.635 -0.635 -0.635
5    -155 -0.6700 -0.6700 -0.6700 -0.670 -0.670 -0.670 -0.670 -0.670 -0.670 -0.670
6    -150 -0.7700 -0.7700 -0.7700 -0.770 -0.770 -0.770 -0.770 -0.770 -0.770 -0.770
7    -145 -0.9000 -0.9000 -0.9000 -0.900 -0.900 -0.900 -0.900 -0.900 -0.900 -0.900
8      -4  0.0581  0.3041  0.4186  0.440  0.440  0.440  0.440  0.440  0.440  0.440
9      -3  0.0725  0.2452  0.3078  0.330  0.330  0.330  0.330  0.330  0.330  0.330
10     -2  0.0715  0.1740  0.2099  0.220  0.220  0.220  0.220  0.220  0.220  0.220
11     -1  0.0434  0.0891  0.1054  0.110  0.110  0.110  0.110  0.110  0.110  0.110
12      0  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
14      1  0.0434  0.0891  0.1054  0.110  0.110  0.110  0.110  0.110  0.110  0.110
15      2  0.0715  0.1740  0.2099  0.220  0.220  0.220  0.220  0.220  0.220  0.220
16      3  0.0725  0.2452  0.3078  0.330  0.330  0.330  0.330  0.330  0.330  0.330
17      4  0.0581  0.3041  0.4186  0.440  0.440  0.440  0.440  0.440  0.440  0.440
18    145 -0.9000 -0.9000 -0.9000 -0.900 -0.900 -0.900 -0.900 -0.900 -0.900 -0.900
19    150 -0.7700 -0.7700 -0.7700 -0.770 -0.770 -0.770 -0.770 -0.770 -0.770 -0.770
20    155 -0.6700 -0.6700 -0.6700 -0.670 -0.670 -0.670 -0.670 -0.670 -0.670 -0.670
21    160 -0.6350 -0.6350 -0.6350 -0.635 -0.635 -0.635 -0.635 -0.635 -0.635 -0.635
22    165 -0.6800 -0.6800 -0.6800 -0.680 -0.680 -0.680 -0.680 -0.680 -0.680 -0.680
23    170 -0.8500 -0.8500 -0.8500 -0.850 -0.850 -0.850 -0.850 -0.850 -0.850 -0.850
24    175 -0.6600 -0.6600 -0.6600 -0.660 -0.660 -0.660 -0.660 -0.660 -0.660 -0.660
25    180  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
```

Comment: From one pandas answerer to another.  I use these pandas options to streamline some stuff.  `pd.set_option('display.notebook_repr_html', False, 'expand_frame_repr', False, 'display.max_colwidth', 50, 'display.max_rows', 101)`.  This makes `print(df)` moot as it by default displays as text.

Comment: The result dataframe should be sorted along `alpha` starting -180 to 180

Comment: @piRSquared thank you so much for that! was looking ages to find a solution to that. Is there already something about that on SO? Else you should make that a Q&A, because I think more people are looking for this

Comment: @Freshman42 we just need to change the order of the `pd.concat`, see updated answer for correct output

Comment: The `alpha = 0` is duplicated it should be  removed

Comment: See updated answer @Freshman42 , next time try to add `expected output` so people understand what you want to achieve